# Is there a word meaning "to assess from afar" or something similar?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ideally, something that means to appraise or assess value from a distance.

I don't think there is going to be such a word.

But something similar, like to assess a situation, or to assess risk could be close analogues for what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Consider changing the phrase *close to it* in your title to the word *similar* so that the *afar/close* relationship doesn't make the word *it* mean *the thing assessed*.

Comment: It might clarify things a bit if you were to explain what you mean by 'distance.' Is that geographic, psychological or visual (and so on) distance?

Answer (score -3):

"**Fly-on-the-wall** observation is an observation technique where you can place yourself in a non-obtrusive position and observe from a distance. ..." - loft.io

Comment: Being a fly on the wall is specifically ***not*** observing from a distance, but observing, unnoticed, “right there in the room” as it were.